# Loading Multiple sheets and exporting to one sheet for excel

Tags: c#, database, excel, sharepoint

I am currently documenting changes to a specific excel file in Sharepoint. Basically, we are taking the versions of the file, getting the sheet in which to load, grabbing the data in that sheet and loading that data to another sheet in another workbook. I have everything in place, but I am looking for the best method for loading multiple sheets of data and putting it into one, the only problem is that most of the columns do not match. So in my head I have figured I should just copy the column headers from the latest version, then with the older versions, check to see if the columns match up and if they don't create another column at the end.

I am sure that this will take too long and I only really need this for a one time deal, because after that we will just add the new version to the sheet and it should take two seconds.

I am just looking for the best method, or proven methods. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the question, you are asking how to concatenate tables while adding the necessary columns.

If you are doing this in C#, I suggest that you create a Dictionary that maps the column name in to the column number in the accumulator sheet. Now, you can easily map the columns from each of the source sheets to the accumulator sheet and add a new one when the Dictionary has no key for it.